# Does cuckolding porn usually involve interracial sex with an African-American male?

Tags: racism, pornography

A GQ article [states](https://www.gq.com/story/why-angry-white-men-love-calling-people-cucks)

> The cultural importance of the cuckold in America is rooted in racism: **in pornography, the wife of the cuckolded (almost exclusively white) husband is most commonly sleeping with African-American men,** meant to provide an additional layer of humiliation if the white husband sees that man as “inferior.” In the world of pornography meant to elicit humiliation as an erotic sentiment, cuckold porn takes advantage of its viewers’ racist perceptions.

Is the highlighted claim about cuckolding porn true, i.e. in cuckolding porn is the actual sex act typically done by an African-American man (with a white woman)? Or is this at least historically true, e.g. in vintage porn?

Comment: I am not at all sure that the statement that African-American men are "inferior" is true in porn. The humiliation part works just as well with a "superior" male. Which makes the whole claim a bit flimsy IMHO; i.e. even if most cuckold porn *were* with African-American men as the active part, I don't think that allows this kind of conclusion ("racist!"). -- Do I understand correctly that you are looking for a third-party *statistical* analysis?

Comment: @DevSolar: something that rigorous might be hard to come by when it comes to porn. At least, do academics writing about cuckolding porn (outside of this recent & narrow alt-right meme context) agree with that assertion that African-Americans were commonly featured in such scenes?

Comment: "Academics writing about cuckolding porn"? Is there such a thing? -- If you're willing to head over to one of the "usual suspects" of adult websites, you'll probably find that the point about the *usualness* of this constellation is *trivially true*. As I said, I am not at all sure about the validity of the conclusion. Actually, that conclusion *itself* (African-American -> inferior) smacks of racism. Possibly related: [Is there a correlation between penis size and race?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/2737/25415)

Comment: @DevSolar: sources surely exist https://doi.org/10.1080/23268743.2018.1555053 (there's even a dedicated journal as you can see "Porn Studies") That paper might a bit too new, i.e. it hits at the alt-right meme from the abstract.

Comment: @Fizz I think this genre is more about this black man being superior in bed in the mind of the American white woman, in the same vein as "once you go black you never go back" and the thinking that black guys are "hung".

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I can answer my own question well enough from one [recent study](https://doi.org/10.1080/23268743.2018.1555053):

> In order to offer contemporary porn references and some idea of the breadth of videos
>   that are being tagged as cuckold, I have put together a brief empirical section. Obviously,
>   this is by no means an exhaustive analysis of videos considered cuckold porn. But it does
>   capture the first pages of results on one of the most popular streaming sites, and hopefully
>   gives some credence to the textual analysis that follows. I went through **the first 100 hits
>   on XVideos that appear with the search ‘cuckold’** (XVideos 2018). As per the heteronormative
>   search function, these only bring up videos tagged straight (gay and trans videos are
>   excluded unless the search is coupled with a gay or trans term). Of all the videos, **only 67
>   were ‘traditional’ cuckold videos depicting an on-screen cuckold, his partner, and a cuckolder.
>   Within these, a white cuckold was depicted 66 times (the only non-white cuckold
>   being Indian).** The cuckold performed unequivocally queer acts in 19 of them – usually
>   a clean-up of his partner’s vagina or mouth-to-mouth cum-swapping, but also a few blowjobs,
>   rim-jobs, and a facial. One-third of the videos did not depict a cuckold. The implication
>   might be that cuckold is the camera person, or perhaps the viewer, or maybe
>   some of the videos appeared due to lazy or clickbait tagging. A small number (three
>   videos) depicted interactions between a putative cuckold and a dominatrix.
>
> **In terms of the cuckolder’s race, the ratio was 67:25 black to white (46:17 in the ‘traditional’
>   videos), excluding the compilation videos which depicted both black and white
>   cuckolders.** In the 30 videos without an on-screen cuckold, the putative cuckolder was
>   usually black (21 videos), and in eight of them he was white. **The female partner was
>   white 96 times (65 of the 67 ‘traditional’ videos).** In the other four, three were East
>   Asian and one was Indian. **Tellingly, black women were never depicted as partners of
>   the cuckold; the only black woman appearing in the surveyed videos joins in with the
>   black man (her partner) and the cuckold’s white wife.** Some of the ‘non-traditional’
>   videos included one tagged ‘reverse cuckold’, featuring a man and two women, one
>   gagged and bound – all of whom were white. Others were simple male–male–female
>   bisexual videos with no humiliation element. Four were labelled ‘mom cuckold’, where
>   a young white woman watches her ‘mother’ have sex with a black man. These seemed
>   to have no humiliation element, either.
>
> **Twenty-one of the videos featured white-on-white cuckoldry. With race not directly at
>   issue, these videos make up the ‘difference’ between cuckold and cuckolder in their physical
>   attributes (the cuckolder is a stud, the cuckold is not).** In five of these videos, there was
>   reciprocity in the appearance of the white men, and these might be better classified as the
>   typical male–male–female bisexual porn mentioned earlier, with no performance of humiliation.
>   Or, perhaps, they truly were considered cuckold videos by the creator/uploader,
>   wherein the white cuckold has little inspiration to perform the kind of anxiety reserved
>   for white cuckolds encountering black men. Yet there were still examples of white-onwhite,
>   ‘traditional’ cuckold porn which showcase, among other elements, the cuckold’s
>   psychological torment at the sight of his wife’s infidelity, his submission to the cuckolder,
>   and the ‘forced’ performance of queer acts. So, on one level, race clearly is not a necessary
>   condition for a video to be a cuckold porn text. **The subgenre as a whole, however, is undeniably
>   obsessed with, if not predicated on, interracial sex. The cuckold and his wife/girlfriend
>   are almost always white, and the cuckolder is black two-thirds of the time.** The
>   near irrelevance near irrelevance of black women (and women of colour, generally) to the fantasy is made well apparent.

So, it seem the claim is quite *true* based on this sample.

Comment: Interestingly, that same study also seconds my question mark put to the "black -> inferior" part of the claim: *"...these videos bake up the 'difference' between cuckold and cuckolder in their physical attributes (the cuckolder is a stud, the cuckold is not)."*

Comment: I am seeing a potential methodic problem in this study. Its data sample were the top 100 picks of XVideos search function. So the results might be biased by how XVideos ranks its search results. Does it rank them by date? By user rating? By popularity? Maybe it even personalizes the search based on what it knows about the user who makes the search query?